# Allow both alpha and digit input when my program keeps returning the same thing

Tags: python

```
employee = float(raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:'))

if employee == 24:
     print "Welcome Kobe Bryant"
     print """

                                                                           ________________   
                                                                __________/________________\_________
                                                               //                                   \\
                                                              //                                     \\
                                                             ||                                      ||
                                                          ||                                      ||
                                                             ||                                      ||
                                                             ||                                      ||
                                                             |      _ \\  //  /\          _  _____     |
                                                             | _   ^  ) \\//  //\\    /\\   //|__ __/    |
                                                             |\  ) \\ \\  \/  //--\\  // \\ //   //       |
                                                             | \  ) \\ \\ || //    \\//   \\/   //        |
                                                             |  \/                                    |
         ===///    , ,-. ,-   .-, , , ,-  ,-  ,  ,- ,-       |       -------          ,-----          |
         --///    /_ |_/ _)  /--|/|/ |_] /=_ /_ /=_ _)       |     /  ___   \        / /|  |          |
       ___///    __    __  __  ______  ____    ___           |    / /     \  \      / / |  |          |
         ///  --/||  --//  /   //   / _//  )) (|  /          |   /_/      /  /     / /  |  |          |
     ---///   /' ||  _// //   //__    //_ //   \\             |          /  /      / /   |  |          |
     --///- -/---||  // ||   //     _//  ||     \\     ;      |         /  /      / /____|  |___       |
______/// __/_  _||_//   ||_//___/ _//   |\ /-._//    /      |       /  /       |_______    ___|      |
    _///     ,                            \\       .'         |     /   /_______         |  |          |
 ___///_____/                              `;=__.-'          |    |____________|        |__|          |
                                                             |                                        |
                                                             |                                        |
                                                             |                                        |
                                                             |________________________________________|
                                                             |________________________________________|



"""

if employee < 23:
    print""
    print"""\t\tWelcome Guest
Please Enter Item Price! If you enter a letter the program will crash! """

if employee > 24:
    print ""
    print"""\t\tWelcome GAVIN WHITFORT
Please Enter Item Price! If you enter a letter the program will crash!
"""

if employee == 23:
    print " "
    print """\t\t     WELCOME THE GOAT MICHAEL JORDAN"""
    print """         (Greatest of All Time)
    *                        CHICAGO                        *
   ***                        BULLS                        ***
   ****                        23                         ****
   *   ******                                       ******   *
   *         ***************************************         *
    **            *       ______*______       *            **
      *****      *        ______*______        *      *****
           *******        ______*______        *******
        ***       ****          *         ****        ***
            ****** *oo*******  ***  *******oo* ******
                 *   *o********* *********o*   *
                  *   *                   *   *
                   *   *   _         _   *   *
                    *   *  -_       _-  *   *
                     *  *   -_     _-   *  *
                      * *     -___-     * *
                       *                 *
                      *********************
                      *      **   **      *
                        *    **   **    *
                          *  _-----_  *
                            *********

                    ************                      .                             
               .e$**%    $    %%*$e.               
             z$**.       $         $$c                        
           z$*   *.      $       .P  ^$c                      
          d*      *      $      z       b                     
         $*        b     $     4%       ^$                    
        d%         *     $     P         '$                   
       .$           F    $    J           $r                  
       4L...........b....$....$...........J$                  
       $F           F    $    $           4$                  
       4F          4F    $    4r          4P                  
       ^$          $     $     b          $%                  
        3L        .F     $      r        JP                   
         *c       $      $       3.     z$                    
          *b     J       $        3r   dP                     
           ^$c  z%       $         c z$7                      
              *$L        $        .d$6                        
                 *$ee..  $  ..ze$P                  
                    ***********        """      





if(employee.isalpha()):
    print"Nice try buddy"
    print"Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
else:
    print "Welcome Guest"
    print "your emplyee # is:" + str(employee)
```

The program keeps printing welcome GAVIN WHITFORT without considering the input.

Comment: why `float`, looks like `int`?

Comment: you can also simplify your example by removing multiline messages

Answer (score 0):

I get errors about float conversion running your code. So I make some simplification on your code and reorganized part of it. The core idea here is try to parse your input with int() and do something else if exceptions are caguht(i.e. non-digit characters input)

```
employee = raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:')

try:
    employee_id = int(employee)
    print "Welcome Guest"
    print "your emplyee # is:" + str(employee)
    if employee_id == 24:
        print "Welcome Kobe"
    elif employee_id < 23:
        print "Guest"
    elif employee_id > 24:
        print "Gavin"
    elif employee_id == 23:
        print "Jordan"
except:
    print"Nice try buddy"
    print"Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
```

And I suggest to extract a function to make it more clearer.

```
def welcome_employee_by_id(employee_id):
    if employee_id == 24:
        print "Welcome Kobe"
    elif employee_id < 23:
        print "Guest"
    elif employee_id > 24:
        print "Gavin"
    elif employee_id == 23:
        print "Jordan"
    # Try to reorganize the order and add border conditions
    # to make it more clear

employee = raw_input('Employee code number or 0 for guest:')

try:  # this deals with digit input
    employee_id = int(employee)
    print "Welcome Guest"
    print "your emplyee # is:" + employee
    welcome_employee_by_id(employee_id)
except: # deals with input if it cannot be converted to int
    print "Nice try buddy"
    print "Welcome BIG_OLD_BUDDY"
```

> [Input] abc
>
> [Output] Nice try buddy...
>
> [Input] 24
>
> [Output] Welcome Guest
>   your emplyee # is:24
>   Welcome Kobe
>
> [Input] Kobe24
>
> [Output] Nice try buddy...